# Change highlighted repeated code in BigQuery SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, keyboard-shortcuts

I am learning SQL and I noticed that when you select code that is repeated, it gets highlighted.
My question is if there is any way to change all that repeated code at once, instead of manually changing it.

[example of what I mean]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOfCv.png

I bet there is just a keyboard shortcut, but I couldn't find it.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

In the query editor, right click the repeated code and select `Change all Occurrences` or Ctrl+F2:

[image]